# How to get value of element in the same array when initialize

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I Think it's a strange question :

i dont need answer with loop or push to array i'm just wondering about the idea

I'm trying ti initialize an array ,, but i need to read the previous element like this,

```
return $recourd_list = array(
                'clients'=> array(
                    'route' =>   'clients.index',
                    'title' =>   'fullname',
                    'list'  =>   Clients::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
                    'count' =>   Clients::count(),
                    'class' =>   'bgm-lightgreen',
                    'diff'  =>   5 - $recourd_list['clients']['count'],
                    ),

                'sliders'=> array(
                    'route' =>   'sliders',
                    'title' =>   'title',
                    'list'  =>   Sliders::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
                    'count' =>   Sliders::count(),
                    'class' =>   'bgm-rightBlue Oil-color',
                    'diff'  =>   5 - $recourd_list['sliders']['count'],
                ),
                'sponsors'=> array(
                    'route' =>   'sponsors.index',
                    'title' =>   'title',
                    'list'  =>   Sponsors::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
                    'count' =>   Sponsors::count(),
                    'class' =>   'bgm-nave dark-green',
                    'diff'  =>   5 - $recourd_list['sponsors']['count'],
                    ),
                'packages'=> array(
                    'route' =>   'packages',
                    'title' =>   'title',
                    'list'  =>   Packages::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
                    'count' =>   Packages::count(),
                    'class' =>   'bgm-bluegray',
                    'diff'  =>   5 - $recourd_list['packages']['count'],
                    ),
                'event_schedule'=> array(
                    'route' =>   'event_schedule.index',
                    'title' =>   'title',
                    'list'  =>   EventSchedule::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
                    'count' =>   EventSchedule::count(),
                    'class' =>   'bgm-orange',
                    'diff'  =>   5 - $recourd_list['event_schedule']['count'],
                    ),
        );
```

I need to read the count element in diff element .. is that way to do that when initialize array

Thanks All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible as the array technically won't be defined at that point.

One way to achieve this would be to use something like `array_map`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

```
$recourd_list = array(
    'clients'=> array(
        'route' =>   'clients.index',
        'title' =>   'fullname',
        'list'  =>   Clients::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' =>   Clients::count(),
        'class' =>   'bgm-lightgreen',
    ),

    'sliders'=> array(
        'route' =>   'sliders',
        'title' =>   'title',
        'list'  =>   Sliders::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' =>   Sliders::count(),
        'class' =>   'bgm-rightBlue Oil-color',
    ),
    'sponsors'=> array(
        'route' =>   'sponsors.index',
        'title' =>   'title',
        'list'  =>   Sponsors::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' =>   Sponsors::count(),
        'class' =>   'bgm-nave dark-green',
    ),
    'packages'=> array(
        'route' =>   'packages',
        'title' =>   'title',
        'list'  =>   Packages::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' =>   Packages::count(),
        'class' =>   'bgm-bluegray',
    ),
    'event_schedule'=> array(
        'route' =>   'event_schedule.index',
        'title' =>   'title',
        'list'  =>   EventSchedule::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' =>   EventSchedule::count(),
        'class' =>   'bgm-orange',
    ),
);
```

then

```
return array_map(function ($item) {
    $item['diff'] = $item['count'] - 5;

    return $item;
}, $recourd_list);
```

Alternatively, you could use `map` with `Collections`
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map

```
return collect($recourd_list)->map(function ($item) {
    $item['diff'] = $item['count'] - 5;

    return $item;
})->toArray();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

short answer:
**no.**

But since you are, at init time, defining the Count, why not do this:

```
'diff' => 5 - Clients::count(),
```

so with the entire example:

```
return $recourd_list = array(
    'clients' => array(
        'route' => 'clients.index',
        'title' => 'fullname',
        'list' => Clients::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' => Clients::count(),
        'class' => 'bgm-lightgreen',
        'diff' => 5 - Clients::count(),
    ),

    'sliders' => array(
        'route' => 'sliders',
        'title' => 'title',
        'list' => Sliders::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' => Sliders::count(),
        'class' => 'bgm-rightBlue Oil-color',
        'diff' => 5 - Sliders::count(),
    ),
    'sponsors' => array(
        'route' => 'sponsors.index',
        'title' => 'title',
        'list' => Sponsors::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' => Sponsors::count(),
        'class' => 'bgm-nave dark-green',
        'diff' => 5 - Sponsors::count(),
    ),
    'packages' => array(
        'route' => 'packages',
        'title' => 'title',
        'list' => Packages::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' => Packages::count(),
        'class' => 'bgm-bluegray',
        'diff' => 5 - Packages::count(),
    ),
    'event_schedule' => array(
        'route' => 'event_schedule.index',
        'title' => 'title',
        'list' => EventSchedule::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get(),
        'count' => EventSchedule::count(),
        'class' => 'bgm-orange',
        'diff' => 5 - EventSchedule::count(),
    ),
);
```

Comment: i know that but i dont need to duplicate the query and ask about the idea